# Can I assign the values to datagridview cells at a time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Can I assign the values to datagridview cells at a time like

***datagridview1[0,0].value = "zero column zero row"***

***datagridview1[1,0].value = "first column zero row"***

***datagridview1[0,1].value = "zero column first row"***

***datagridview1[1,1].value = "first column first row"***

It gives error ***Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    // Define 
    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

    // Assign
    dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = "zero column zero row";
    dataGridView1[1, 0].Value = "first column zero row";
    dataGridView1[0, 1].Value = "zero column first row";
    dataGridView1[1, 1].Value = "first column first row";
```

There is some "magic" that takes places behind the scenes.  According to the [MSDN document for the Cells property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.cells.aspx):

> If the row does not contain any cells
>   when this property is accessed, a new
>   empty DataGridViewCellCollection  will
>   be created by a call to the
>   CreateCellsInstance  method.

By specifying the `ColumnCount` and calling the `Rows.Add` method the the DataGridView has enough meta information to automatically create new Rows when directly accessing the Cells property.

Comment: Ok. It works...But does not datagridview dynamically set its no of rows and columns according to our code ? Any property or any other code do that ?

Comment: yes, you are right, so what you can do is, move the entire code to grid view's data bound event and just put a for loop on rows first and then columns to get what you want to do ;)